# call CLP (a linear programming solver writen in C++) from C# .net in VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wrapper, linear-programming, clp

I need to call CLP (a linear programming solver writen in C++) from C# .net (4.0, 4.5) in VS2013.

```
 http://www.coin-or.org/Clp/userguide/clpuserguide.html
```

I have search some links about how to call C++ lib from C#.

I found the possible options:

1. use the C# warpper

   http://astarte.csr.unibo.it/coinORwrapper/coinORwrapper.htm
2. Design wrapper class myself.

   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-minutes

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/299da822-5539-4e5b-9ba7-b614e564c9f4/presenting-a-c-library-lib-for-use-in-c-project

CLP has too many classes so I try to avoid writing a wrapper class for each class. This may cause too many errors.

The first option has no English document, and has errors.

Are there other ways to call CLP from C# ?

thanks

Comment: You also could write an LP/MPS file from C# and then spawn an executable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a third option, you have [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). But that is a mess that you should not get into if you don't know enough C++ to use C++ to call this library.

I don't know what exactly you want to do with CLP, but have you considered using other products that interface better with your language of choice? Could for example the [Solver Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524509(v=vs.93).aspx) be an alternative choice?

Comment: Solver Foundation has been discontinued.